# Update: mesh grid project

Tags: python, grid, dot

I have an assignment that is requiring us to create a dot grid along with a curser that moves up, down, right, left, on the grid when given the command. I can't get my move functions to work along with the grid showing with the updated coordinate. This is what I have so far.

Comment: Why did you remove the code from the question? As it is now the question is of no use and ends with "This is what I have so far. "  i.e looks like you don't have anything.

Comment: I posted a new question, I wasn't sure that if I just edited the question it would refresh.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510682/move-functions-for-mesh-grid/60510833#60510833

Comment: Well in that case you should remove this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it might be an import issue or you need to define method for `show_grid(x,y)`. Let me know if this helps!