# UPDATE: Mesh grid PYTHON

Tags: python, loops, grid

I'm working on a mesh grid that has a cursor that moves when you enter the assigned number. I was able to get the cursor to move, the only problem I'm having is that I want it to print out the location of the updated coordinates as the cursor moves, (ex. if the cursor moves down one block the new location should be (0,-1)). 
[image: THIS IS WHAT THE OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE]

```
x = y = 0
size = int(input('Enter grid size: '))
print(f'Current location: ({x},{y})')

def show_grid(x, y):
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if i == y and j == x:
                print('+', end=' ')
            else:
                print('.', end=' ')
        print()
show_grid(x,y)

def show_menu():
    print('-- Navigation --')
    print('2 : Down')
    print('8 : Up')
    print('6 : Right')
    print('4 : Left')
    print('5 : Reset')
    print('0 : EXIT')
    return 0
show_menu()

choice = int(input('Enter an option: '))            ####current location not updating
def move(x, y, choice):
    if choice == 2:     # down
        show_grid(x, y+1)
    elif choice == 8:   # up
        show_grid(x, y-1)
    elif choice == 4:   # left
        show_grid(x-1, y)
    elif choice == 6:   # right
        show_grid(x+1, y)
    elif choice == 5:   # reset to (0,0)
        show_grid(x, y)
    elif choice == 1:
        print(choice, 'Not a valid input. Try again.')
        show_grid(x, y)
    elif choice == 3:
        print(choice, 'Not a valid input. Try again.')
        show_grid(x, y)
    elif choice == 7:
        print(choice, 'Not a valid input. Try again.')
        show_grid(x, y)
    elif choice == 9:
        print(choice, 'Not a valid input. Try again.')
        show_grid(x, y)
move(x, y, choice)



#main program
while True:
    choice = show_menu()
    if choice == 0:
        print(f'Current location: ({x},{y})')
        break
    else:
        x,y = move(x,y,choice)
    print(f'Current location: ({x},{y})')
    if 0 <= x < size and 0 <= y < size:  # inside the board
        print(f'Current location: ({x},{y})')
    else:  # outside the board
        print('The new location is off the board.')
        break
    print('Exit the program')
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  What input do you provide, what should the program do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: The board is dot grid(like the pic above), and the cursor is a (+) sign, the functions are supposed to be: press 2 (moves + down one), press 8(move up), press 4(moves left), press 6(moves right), press 0(exit), press 5(resets + to (0,0)).

Comment: I have the functions, but when I run it, it does nothing, just prints the menu again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your definition of `move()`, you are using `return` (ie, exiting the function) before you get to the part that calls `show_grid()`

EDIT: instead of returning, just set x, y to whatever they need to be.  Also, I noticed one other thing that may be causing you problems.  You use `option` to decide what to do next, and `option = show_menu()`.  But the way you've defined `show_menu()`, it always returns 0.  In order for `options` to contain the user's input, you should either change the way `show_menu()` is defined, or change the way `option` is assigned.

Edit after OP's update:
Here are the problems that I see

1. In your function `show_menu()`: you never asked for any input from the user.  You are always returning `0`.
2. In your function `move()`: `x` and `y` are not updated.  You're passing the updated `x` and `y` to `show_grid()`, but after that they are not used.
3. You currently `break` out of your `#main program` if `choice == 0`.

Here's what you'll have to do to fix each of the problems I mentioned above:

1. In your function `show_menu()`: ask for the user's input and return it instead of 0.
2. Return the new values of `x` and `y` that you are currently passing to `show_grid()`.
3. Remove `break`.  If you do this without fixing #1 first you'll end up in an infinite loop - but if you fix #1 first it will wait for user input.

Comment: Ohhh ok I see, what would be a better option?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add some information that may help you.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the "+" to move, now the only problem is that the location of the coordinates are not updating as the x and y move?

Comment: I added some more information based on your update.